# syntax error: unexpected end of input parseJSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm on about hour 5 of this and figure it's time to ask for help. I'm trying to use AJAX+php to upload an image and some text data on a form to a database. The total system is:

an input page with a form, `social.php`
a php processing page, `postMsg.php`
and a javascript function `postMsg()` that posts the form to the php processing page and is supposed to return the results to a div on `social.php`

The problem is that the $.parseJSON(data) command in the javascript results in an "unexpected end of input" error:

```
Failed:  
SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected end of input"}
(index):156
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery.js:4235
b.extend.parseJSON jquery.js:4235
(anonymous function) (index):158
c jquery.js:4611
p.fireWith jquery.js:4687
k jquery.js:10335
r
```

I thought there was an issue with my javascript, but I code-checked it and it's fine:

```
     function postMsg() {
        console.log("submit event");
        var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("commentSubmit"));
        fd.append("label", "WEBUPLOAD");
        document.getElementById('progressBar').style.display = 'block';

        $.ajax({
          url: "postMsg.php",
          type: "POST",
          xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
          },
          data: fd,
          enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
          processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
          contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        }).done(function( data ) {
            console.log("PHP Output:");
            console.log( data );

            try {responseData = $.parseJSON(data)}
            catch (e) {console.log('Failed: ', e, data);}

            var items = $.parseJSON(data);
            document.getElementById('progressBar').style.display = 'none';
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Then I thought there was an issue with my php, but replaced it all with a simple command and it still resulted in the same error:

```
$json_array = array('selfie'=>'hello');
```

Then I thought there might be an issue with my input form, so I rewrote that, but it's still returning the same error:

```
echo '<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="margin-top: -30px;margin-bottom: -30px;border-bottom: 0px;">
                <form method="post" name="commentSubmit" id="commentSubmit">
                  <div style="width=100%; font-size:.9em;" data-role="fieldcontain">
                  <label class="ui-input-text" for="msg_txt">Chip in:</label>';

//          $selfie = get_selfie($uid);
        echo '<div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; display: block; font-size:.9em">';

echo '<input name="file" type="file">';
        echo '<textarea style="width:100% text-align:left; font-weight:normal;" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-c" data-iconshadow="true" data-shadow="true" data-corners="false" cols="23" rows="1" name="msg_txt" id="msg_txt"></textarea>';
        echo '<a style="border-radius:8px" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-right ui-controlgroup-last ui-btn-up-c" title="My button" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconshadow="true" onclick="postMsg();" data-shadow="true" data-corners="true" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-right ui-controlgroup-last"><span class="ui-btn-text">My button</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a>';
        echo '<div id="photoUploaded" style="display: none;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
opacity: .5;
color: black;
float: right; 
vertical-align: middle;
font-family: sans-serif;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 10px;">photo loaded</div>';

                  echo '<input name="refresh" value="1" id="refresh" type="hidden">
                    <input name="uname" value="'.get_name($uid).'" id="uname" type="hidden">
                    <input name="uid" value="'.$uid.'" id="uname" type="hidden">

                </form>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: well sounds like JSON is not being returned

Comment: What did you get `console.log( data );`?

Comment: this is what i get from the console: 

submit event (index):132
PHP Output: (index):152
 (index):153
Failed:  
SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected end of input"}
message: "Unexpected end of input"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error

Comment: Are you using the php function json_encode($yourArray) ? This will ensure you're outputting in correct json format

Comment: this is the php function: `$json_array = array('selfie'=>'hello');`

Comment: Sorry, there's one more line on the php function: 
json_encode($json_array);

Comment: @mobro put dataType:"json" in your jquery ajax please and let me now if it works for you.

Comment: An apostrophe can also wrecking havoc, I got the exact same error message, used debugger and saw that my string was broken where there was an apostrophe. So I replaced the apostrophe with html entity &#39;

Answer (score 11):

This plagued me for sometime as most of the answers to this same question get caught running down rabbit holes. Plus, the answer is hidden *DEEP* within the `jquery` documentation for the ajax object. Without further ado:

[jQuery.ajax:**dataType**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

Ergo, you must always at least return an empty JSON object or null from any request in order for `jquery` to accept it as valid.

Comment: Is there a way to tell jQuery (Or Backbone in my case) to ignore this particular error? I'm in a situation where I can't control the responses from the server (Conveniently).

Comment: Had the same issue with .NET Core. Had to return an HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: @AnalogWeapon try, catch block I would imagine. Or you could crawl into the jquery code and try to figure out how to monkeypatch whatever is throwing the error.